# A question on the sylow subgroups of a normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

$H$ normal subgroup of a group $G$ with cardinality finite. $p$ prime number dividing $|H|$. $P$ a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $H$, how can I prove that then $G=HN_G(P)$ where $N_G(P)$ is the normalizer of $P$ in $G$?

Comment: This is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frattini's_argument

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $g\in G$, then $gHg^{-1}=H$, and so $gPg^{-1}\subseteq H$. Since $gPg^{-1}$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $H$, by Sylow's Theorems we know that $gPg^{-1}$ is conjugate to $P$ *in $H$*. That is, there exists $h\in H$ such that $hPh^{-1} = gPg^{-1}$. Therefore, $g^{-1}hPh^{-1}g = P$, so $h^{-1}g\in N_G(P)$.